# Cross Compiling Haskell

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling, ghc

How can I cross-compile Haskell to an ARM processor?

I've already been able to cross-compile C, Go and Rust, so, I guess, this isn't a problem in my toolchain?

I was able to run the configure script from ghc source code, although running hadrian I get errors. In order to try to achieve my goals, I did the following commands:

```bash
export CXX=/home/username/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang++
export CC=/home/username/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang
export LD=/home/username/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld
export AR=/home/username/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar

./configure --target aarch64-linux-android29
hadrian/build -j --verbose
```

And the last instruction gives me the following error:

```bash
| Run Ghc LinkHs (Stage0 InTreeLibs): _build/stage0/utils/haddock/build/Main.o (and 49 more) => _build/stage0/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-haddock
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-cc
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-android
Unknown OS android
# _build/stage1/rts/build/include/ghcautoconf.h
| ContextData oracle: resolving data for 'rts' (Stage1, v)...
| ContextData oracle: resolving data for 'rts' (Stage1, v)...
Error when running Shake build system:
  at action, called at src/Rules.hs:39:19 in main:Rules
  at need, called at src/Rules.hs:61:5 in main:Rules
* Depends on: _build/stage1/lib/package.conf.d/rts-1.0.2.conf
  at apply1, called at src/Development/Shake/Internal/Rules/Oracle.hs:159:32 in shake-0.19.7-d5ed83c858bf166c2267f32ca7608d79b8ca2402f05e75acba55d9c6a59cf591:Development.Shake.Internal.Rules.Oracle
* Depends on: OracleQ (ContextDataKey (Context {stage = Stage1, package = Package {pkgType = Library, pkgName = "rts", pkgPath = "rts"}, way = v, iplace = Final}))
* Depends on: _build/stage1/rts/setup-config
* Raised the exception:
ExitFailure 1

Build failed.
```

I already verified and the paths to CXX, CC, LD and AR are correct.

Am I missing something?
Should I install something else?

Comment: Which documentation are you reading? The `configure` script is part of the GHC source code, which you'll need if you want to build a cross compiler because there are no prebuilt GHC binaries for cross compilation AFAIK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Noughtmare i've already been able to execute the configure script of GHC source code, but now I get an error when trying to run "hadrian/build -j".
I've already exported my clang, clang++ and linker from Android NDK and the configure script is working correctly (I think), but I'm getting "Unknown OS android ExitFailure 1 Build Failed" on "hadrian/build", do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: It would help if you expanded your question with all the commands you ran and what the results were.

Comment: @Noughtmare updated with the executed commands

Comment: Maybe this is relevant [If configure complains that your arch, vendor or OS is unknown, then you will need to modify the checkArch(), checkVendor() or checkOS() function in aclocal.m4, then get autotools to re-create the configure script using the autoreconf command.](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/building/cross-compiling#configuring-the-build).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may just need to leave out the specific android version, because the [`checkOS` function is defined like this](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/42aa7fbd6cc51f7cd993621336e1c3fa8202ab1f/m4/fptools_set_haskell_platform_vars.m4#L76-78):

```
    checkOS() {
        case [$]1 in
        linux|linux-android)
            test -z "[$]2" || eval "[$]2=OSLinux"
            ;;
```